# Azure app service (Linux) - git deployment error - ENOENT: no such file or directory (manifest file)

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

App service is on Linux.  I have a deployment hooked up to my Git repo for a node.js application.  I don't have a custom deployment script so Azure creates one for me.  The "Running deployment command..." step in the "Deployment Details" blade (see screenshot below) fails with this error:

```
Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Handling node.js deployment.
Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/deployments/6f824c2be05e1a3ed8afce700177318ec96f0203/manifest'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/bin/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
```

Can't find the 'manifest' file.  I used Kudu to SSH into the '/home/site/deployments/6f824c2be05e1a3ed8afce700177318ec96f0203' directory and sure enough the manifest is not there.

I even tried generating my own deployment script using the [kuduscript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kuduscript) npm module, but got same error.

[image]

Activity Logs:
[image]

Comment: Is this App Service on Linux or Windows? Please clarify in the subject/question/tags, as they work rather differently.

Comment: App Service on Linux.

Comment: Ok, I've asked our Linux expert to take a look.

Comment: BTW, the log for the 3rd step ("Generating deployment script.") says:

"Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "/home/site/repository" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --node --sitePath "/home/site/repository"')."


Just a guess, but perhaps deleting this cache might regenerate the manifest?

Comment: It could clean things out, but would be interesting to understand how it got in that state, which I've never seen on the Windows side. So the manifest file is complains about is indeed missing? For a more complete cleanup, you can delete the whole `/home/site/deployments`. Mostly, you'll just lose your deployment history.

Comment: I'm happy to work with you to diagnose the issue before cleanup.  Would you like to email me directly instead of discussing in this forum?  Or perhaps is there value to doing this in a public way?

Comment: @nlawalker is our Kudu Linux expert and will try to help out.

Comment: Hi @nlawalker.  Would you like to do any investigation before I follow David's suggestion to delete the deployments folder?  I kind of blocked so if I don't hear back by Thursday I'll proceed with the deletion.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the lag on this - no investigation from my side. Please let me know if the deletion unblocks you.

Comment: @nlawalker Yes I deleted home/site/deployments and it unblocked me.  Thanks for the follow up.